# Find correlation between million of records in python 3.x

Tags: pandas, matrix, python-3.6, sparse-matrix, pearson-correlation

I have a pandas dataframe as given below, and in which I would like to find the correlation between the customers based on the rating. As per my knowledge, I would have to pivot the dataframe in order to find the correlation between the customers. But I have 9 million customers so pivoting table is not the feasible solution.

```
data = {'customerId':  [681378,295576, 363834, 681378,295576, 363834],
        'dataId': [31132, 26798, 4019, 15856, 16128,15856],
        'rating': [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
        }

train = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['customerId','dataId','rating'])
```

***Train DataFrame ***

```
customerId  dataId  rating
0   681378  31132   2
1   295576  26798   1
2   363834  4019    2
3   681378  15856   1
4   295576  16128   1
```

So, I came up with the solution where I am finding the correlation between two customers at a time. Current and Lengthy Process:

1. Using the nested for loop where first loop takes the first id and calculates the correlation with each customer.
2. In every step do the pivot table before calculating correlation.
3. In the end saving the result to hdf5 pytables so that don't have to calculate correlation again and again.

But this process is taking lot of time. I have attempted to do as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
def createStore():

    store = pd.HDFStore('correlation_df_test.h5')
    return store

start_time_2 = time.time()

list_of_users_in_train = sorted(train.customerId.unique())
total_users_in_train = len(train.customerId.unique())

print("Total customers in train dataframe is {}".format(total_users_in_train))

store = createStore()
customers_already_calculated = []

for i in list_of_users_in_train:
    # iterating all the unique customers
    print("--------------------- i = {} -------------------------".format(i))
    count = 0
    for j in list_of_users_in_train:
        # Calculates correlation with every other customer
        if i != j:
            if j not in customers_already_calculated:

                # fetching only ith and jth customer from the dataframe and pivoting.
                pivoted_data = train.loc[train.customerId.isin([i, j])].pivot_table(values='rating', index='dataId', columns='customerId', fill_value=0)
                # calculate the correlation between the two customers
                corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(pivoted_data.T)
                # converting matrix to dataframe
                corrMatrix_train = pd.DataFrame(corr_matrix, index=pivoted_data.columns, columns=pivoted_data.columns).rename_axis('customerId_y', axis=1)
                # changing the index name
                corrMatrix_train.index.names = ['customerId_x']
                corrMatrix_train = corrMatrix_train.stack().reset_index()
                corrMatrix_train = corrMatrix_train.rename(columns={0: 'correlation_value'})
                # Droping the rows where customerId_x and customerId_y are not same.
                corrMatrix_train = corrMatrix_train.iloc[1:3, :]
                count = count + 1
                # Appending to hdf5 file to read it later.
                store.append('corr_df_test',corrMatrix_train)

    print(count)
    customers_already_calculated.append(i)
    print( "************* count is {} ***************".format(count))



print("--- Time taken to calculate correlation records %s minutes ---" % round(((time.time() - start_time_2)/60),2))
```

**Is the above code can be optimized? Or Is there any better way to do it?**

Comment: If you have 1e7 customers a single precision correlation matrix for them will be about 2e14 bytes. I'd make sure this is an analysis you need before you write 200tb to a file.

Comment: It seems like you're asking about recommendations for statistical algorithms, rather than for tips for implementing a correlation matrix specifically. This would be a better fit for the stack exchange network site [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, I am asking for tips for implementing correlation matrix  for million of columns. I have already implemented recommender system.